# jquery ui disabled button unwanted text shadow in IE

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have link which is a Jquery UI style button.
When I set `disabled="disabled"` ie8 renders the text with a white drop shadow.
I can't tell where it is getting this style from. 
I have inspected the `<a>` tag, and it's two `<span>` children with ie dev tools and there are no styles which seem to relate to this.

I also looked through the UI stylesheet for any `filter:` or `dropshadow` properties, but alas there were none.

I also tried overriding the style even though I couldn't be sure where it was coming from, with:

```
a.ui-state-disabled {

color:black !important;

}
```

But to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post a working example on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Good idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/fnwjT/2/

Comment: where are you getting the class `ui-state-disabled` from?? i alert the classes that the button has, and the only class it has assigned is `button`...

Comment: Right, I hadn't even called button(). In that case it isn't Juquery-UI doing it, it's just what IE does when a link has the attribute "disabled". I just need to figure out how to re-style it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jquery-ui. IE adds its own style to links with attribute disabled="disabled". It can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Adripants is right.It can't be overridden, but you have another way to do it:

**First:** Add your custom disable style to your css stylesheet

```
a.disabled {
    color:black;
}
```

**Then:** Remove the "disabled" attribute and add your custom class only for IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a:disabled, a[disabled='disabled']").addClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
</script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Comment: You should also consider adding a readonly attribute like this:
`$("input:disabled").addClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled").attr("readonly","readonly");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing:

```
<button class="disabled" onmousedown="return checkDisable();">

function checkDisable() {

        if($(this).hasClass('disabled') { return false;}
}
```

Comment: This is terrible for accessibility as the button appears enabled to a screenreader, yet does nothing. Do not do this.